# Using the JavaScript property accessor or optional chaining operator in the browser console

Tags: javascript, browser

If I write an expression that uses the (relatively new) JavaScript's optional chaining operator in the Chrome/Firefox console, I get error:

Firefox (83.0):

[image]

Chrome (87.0.4280.66):

[image]

If I evaluate `{key:123}?.key` in Node.js console (v14.15.0), I get proper `123`.

After I discovered this behaviour, I found out that the same problem is also with the property accessor (".") operator, too. Why this strange behaviour?

Comment: The reason is easy to miss at first. :-) It's because the `{` starts a block when the parser isn't specifically expecting an expression (rather than statement or declaration). Put `()` around the expression, e.g.: `({key:123})?.key` or `({key:123}?.key)` so the parser knows that the `{` is the beginning of an object literal, not a block (since the contents of `()` can only be an expression, not a statement like a block or a declaration).